# how to maintain table orignal order after using dense_rank() in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table :-

```
ID | name | address | code
-----+---------+-----
1  |  b   |   b-11  |  111
2  |  b   |   b-11  |  123
3  |  a   |   a-11  |  456
4  |  a   |   a-11  |  789
```

I need the output like : -

```
id | name | address | code | Addressid
-----+---------+------+----------
 1 |   b  |   b-11  | 111  | 1
 2 |   b  |   b-11  | 123  | 1
 3 |   a  |   a-11  | 456  | 2
 4 |   a  |   a-11  | 789  | 2
```

When I use the following SQL statement I get the desired format but the order of the table gets changed. Can someone tell me how to get `AddressID` column values without changing the table order.

```
select 
    id, name, address, code,
    dense_rank() over (order by name,address) as addressid
from 
    table1
```

with the above code I get the wrong output as -

```
id| name | address | code | Addressid
--+------+---------+------+----------    
3 |   a  | a-11    | 456  | 1
4 |   a  | a-11    | 789  | 1
1 |   b  | b-11    | 111  | 2
2 |   b  | b-11    | 123  | 2
```

Comment: What is the *original order* defined by? In any relational database, you **don't have** any inherent ordering - only if you explicitly apply an `ORDER BY` to your `SELECT`, there is any ordering ....

Comment: there is a primary key column which I forgot to mention. I will update my question

Comment: I have made changes to my question

Comment: *ORDER BY id* - add this - is this what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

As I said - you don't have any order, unless you **explicitly specify it** - so that's all you need to do - specify the ordering you want to have by adding `order by id` to your existing query:

```
select 
    id, name, address, code,
    dense_rank() over (order by name,address) as addressid
from 
    table1
order by
    id
```

Comment: your code is generating addressid as -> 2,2,1,1. However I want the addressid assigned to the rows as 1,1,2,2 and also keeping the orignal order of the table same. For example your code is assigning value 2 for address b-11 , however I need to assign the id 1 to b-11